# Why must pointer trait bounds be specified redundantly?

Tags: rust

Consider the following situation, with two `Trait`s. The first `Trait` is for pointer types, and the second `Trait` is for regular objects. The second trait has a [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/trait-bounds.html#higher-ranked-trait-bounds) so that any reference to a type that implements the second trait, must implement the first trait:

```rust
pub trait PtrTrait {}

pub trait RegTrait
where
    for<'a> &'a Self: PtrTrait,
{
}
```

Yes, this actually works! In the following, the compiler would complain if the first generic `impl` were not included:

```rust
pub struct S();

// Note, this impl IS needed for the next impl to compile.
impl<'a> PtrTrait for &'a S {}

impl RegTrait for S {}
```

**The problem is** that the compiler doesn't seem to remember about this when writing a generic function. The following function definition doesn't compile:

```rust
pub fn bar<T: RegTrait>() {}
```

The error from `rustc` simply says that the trait bound `for<'a> &'a T: PtrTrait` is not satisfied for the type `&'a T`. If I add a `where` clause to the function:

```rust
where for<'a> &'a T: PtrTrait
```

then it works - but why should that be needed if it's already a constraint on the trait itself?

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f097c382606e49e7c4a26300210dc915)